# Interface EtherCAT servo motor with ROS

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-control, servo, ethercat

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone,

i am student and i want to build my own robot arm. I have finished my robot urdf file and MoveIt! setup. Now i have  bought Panasonic Servo and motor(MINAS A5B EtherCAT servo drives). But i can't  communicate servo with Ros and don't know which package i can use.  Should i use ros_control package? Can anyone guide  me?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226843/interface-ethercat-servo-motor-with-ros/) by [dgnikiroat](https://answers.ros.org/users/25971/dgnikiroat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you'll want to look at [ros_ethercat](https://github.com/shadow-robot/ros_ethercat) by Shadow Robot. It's a rewrite of the Ethercat interfacing stack used on the PR2, but `ros_control` capable, more generic and maintained.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgnikiroat](https://answers.ros.org/users/25971/dgnikiroat/) on 2016-02-17**:
Thanks! a very good example!